# How do I restore the tray clock in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

I managed to remove the clock/date display from my system tray.
How do I get it back?

I think I removed it by right-clicking on it and then deselecting some options, but no amount of right-clicking gives me any option to bring it back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right Click on the Start Orb/Button and click Properties.

Under the Taskbar tab, click "Customize" in the notification area section.

[image]

Click "Turn system Icons on or off" on the text link underneath the main section.

[image]

Turn Clock to on.

[image]

Comment: Updated with pictures!